# THREE = require './three'

Tags: three.js, webpack

I want to use 'THREE.js' with 'webpack', like this.

```
THREE = require './three'

//code + THREE.js -> webpack.js
<script src = "webpack.js"></script>
```

This code does not work.

```
<script src = 'three.js'></script>
<script src = 'webpack.js'></script> //not include THREE.js
```

This code goes well. Please tell me the method to use 'THREE.js' using 'require'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "require"-able version of Three.js on npm: https://www.npmjs.org/package/three

This should be compatible with webpack as well.